# Android: Nested bottom sheet click/drag touch event issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androiddesignsupport, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet nested inside another bottom sheet (`FrameLayouts` using the `BottomSheet` layout behavior)

I also have a couple of 'peek views' (`FrameLayouts`) which have click listeners attached, to expand the bottom sheet(s) respectively, when clicked.

So the app basically has 3 main screens. The 'main container', then the first 'bottom sheet', which can be expanded full-screen, and then at the bottom of the first bottom sheet, is the second bottom sheet, which can also be expanded full-screen.

Problem:

When I add a `RecyclerView` to the nested bottom sheet 'container' view, dragging stops working for the second peek view (Sheet 2 Peek). If I remove the peek view `ClickListener` *or* the `RecyclerView`, things seem to work perfectly fine.

Desired result:

Both bottom sheets should remain draggable, and the peek views should be able to be clicked to expand their parent bottom sheet. The bottom sheet should respond to nested scrolls as it would normally.

I've tried removing the `ClickListener` and using touch gestures instead, but nothing I've tried seems to help.

I'm using `v25.3.1` of the design support library, and I'm able to reproduce this problem on a Galaxy S4 running 4.4.4 stock, and a Nexus 6P running 7.1.2 stock. (I don't have any other devices available).

I've also created a test project on github for anyone interested in taking a closer look:
https://github.com/timusus/bottomsheet-test

Here's a couple of screenshots demonstrating the layout:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

The layout structure looks like this (some code omitted for clarity):

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sheet1" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="CustomBottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="64dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sheet1Container"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <CoordinatorLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sheet2
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="CustomBottomSheetBehavior"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="64dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/sheet2Container"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!-- Problematic RecyclerView -->
                <RecyclerView 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <!-- Problematic Click Listener on this view -->
            <FrameLayout 
                android:id="@+id/sheet2PeekView"
                android:layout_height=64dp"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        </CoordinatorLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sheet1PeekView"
            android:layout_height=64dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout/>
```

The `CustomBottomSheetBehavior` is just a simple subclass of `BottomSheetBehavior` which prevents the first sheet from intercepting touch events if the second sheet is expanded or dragging. This allows the second sheet to be dragged from 'expanded' to 'collapsed' without also collapsing the first sheet.

```
public class CustomBottomSheetBehavior<V extends View> extends BottomSheetBehavior<V> {

    private boolean allowDragging = true;

    public void setAllowDragging(boolean allowDragging) {
        this.allowDragging = allowDragging;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent event) {
        if (!allowDragging) {
            return false;
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event);
    }
}
```

I don't believe the customisation of `BottomSheetBehavior` is relevant to this problem, but for completeness, here's how it's used:

```
FrameLayout sheet1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.sheet1);
bottomSheetBehavior1 = (CustomBottomSheetBehavior) BottomSheetBehavior.from(sheet1);

FrameLayout sheet2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.sheet2);
       bottomSheetBehavior2 = (CustomBottomSheetBehavior) BottomSheetBehavior.from(sheet2);
       bottomSheetBehavior2.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                //If the second sheet is expanded or dragging, don't allow the first sheet to respond to touch events.
               if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED || newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                   bottomSheetBehavior1.setAllowDragging(false);
               } else {
                   bottomSheetBehavior1.setAllowDragging(true);
               }
           }
```

I can't seem to figure out if this is to do with the `onInterceptTouchEvent` of the `BottomSheet`, nested scroll handling of the inner `RecyclerView`, `View.ClickListener` stealing touch events, a combination of the above, or something else altogether.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: adding CustomBottomSheetBehavior  via xml; causing error. How can I provide myCustomBottomSheetBehavior through xml?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**FIXED**

> I can't seem to figure out if this is to do with the
> onInterceptTouchEvent of the BottomSheet, nested scroll handling of
> the inner RecyclerView, View.ClickListener stealing touch events, a
> combination of the above, or something else altogether.

It is a combination of the above **CustomBottomSheetBehavior** and **View.ClickListener**

Issue was  **bottomSheetBehavior1** is taking drag event when **getSheet2PeekView** is dragging so detect touch event  on **getSheet2PeekView** and set **bottomSheetBehavior1** dragging `false` and **bottomSheetBehavior2** `true`

---

### Solution

Put this code and your problem is resolved.

```
findViewById(getSheet2PeekViewResId()).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onTouch: ");
            bottomSheetBehavior1.setAllowDragging(false);
            bottomSheetBehavior2.setAllowDragging(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Also created **[Pull Request](https://github.com/timusus/bottomsheet-test/pull/1)** to your repo with fully working changes.

Comment: Grad idea to listen on the touch event.

I acheived the behaviour i wanted via:
bottomSheetDialog.setHideable(false);